# How to handle geolocation pop up

Tags: geolocation, popup, web-testing, katalon-studio

Hi I have tried to use WebUI.alert / dismiss to handle the geolocation alert but the error message return “alert not found”. The alert is actually there.

None of these work. I have double check the import package. I can disable the popup from browser setting or disable pop up on desired capabilities.

Can you please advise other wiser way to do so?

I have googled and fond some other solutions, such as:

Use selenium library, Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
create java.robot instance, rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D); rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AnUU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
elementPresent=WebUI.waitForAlert(10)
if(elementPresent){
    WebUI.acceptAlert()
}
```

This will wait for 10 seconds and only accept the alert if the alert was present.

Comment: Hi I have tried this method (on the enclosed screenshot). It returns error message shows the no alert found

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize it with some predefined values to avoid this alert.

```
chromeDriver.executeScript("window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = 
    function(success){
         var position = {"coords" : {
                                       "latitude": "555", 
                                       "longitude": "999"
                                     }
                         }; 
         success(position);}");
```